# Static readonly field not initialized based on ordering of fields

Tags: c#

I have a public static class that has a number of static methods and static readonly fields.

```
public static class Global
{
    ...
    // Config is a static method in Global.
    public static readonly string FirebaseAuthDomain = Config("FirebaseAuthDomain"); 
    private static readonly string ResourceNameFormat = "{0}.{1}";
    ...
}
```

I get a `NullReferenceException` when I access `ResourceNameFormat`. However, if I move the declaration of `ResourceNameFormat` before `FirebaseAuthDomain` as shown below, it works fine.

```
public static class Global
{
    ...
    private static readonly string ResourceNameFormat = "{0}.{1}";
    // Config is a static method in Global.
    public static readonly string FirebaseAuthDomain = Config("FirebaseAuthDomain"); 
    ...
}
```

It looks like the call to `Config()` has something to do with this behavior, but I can't tell why. What is the difference between these two code snippets?

Comment: Could be that your `Config()`is using `ResourceNameFormat ` in some way ?

Comment: `I get a NullReferenceException when I access ResourceNameFormat.` Can you show us the calling code which experiences the NRE?

Comment: @Tigran Yes, I have just noticed that there are a couple of nested method calls where calling `Config()` results in reading `ResourceNameFormat`. That explains it.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the link, I didn't see that post before.